# How can I define my own ColorFunction?

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, function-construction, color

Suppose I want to define a color function to use more than one graph.  I'd prefer not to type it out every time.  I know that I can set ColorData like this:

```
Unprotect[ColorData];
ColorData["myRainbow"] = 
  Function[x, Blend[{Black, Purple, Blue, Cyan, Green, Yellow, Orange, Red}, x]];
Protect[ColorData]
```

But I'm not sure how I can define my own ColorFunction which uses that ColorData.  For example, if I try to do something like this:

```
Unprotect[ColorFunction];
ColorFunction["myCF"] = Function[{y}, ColorData["myRainbow"][y]];
Protect[ColorFunction];
```

and then try to call that color function with something like this:

```
nd[y_, a_, b_, n_] := (Binomial[b - a + 1, y]*Sum[((-1)^i)*Binomial[y, i]*((y - i)/(b - a + 1))^n, {i, 0, y}]);
myplot[y_] := 
 ArrayPlot[Table[nd[y, 1, K, n], {K, 1, 50}, {n, 1, 50}], 
  ColorFunction -> "myCF", ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  DataReversed -> True, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {Rotate["K", -90 Degree], "N"}]
myplot[5]
```

I get "Value of option ColorFunction -> mine  is not a valid color function, \
or a gradient ColorData entity."  So clearly I have done something wrong here, but I honestly cannot figure out what.  **How do you define your own ColorFunction?**

Comment: Why do it like this?  Unprotecting and redefining system symbols should be a last resort - it's just a bad idea.  In this case you could just define `myColorFunction = 
 Function[x,
  Blend[{Black, Purple, Blue, Cyan, Green, Yellow, Orange, Red}, x]]`, and then in your plot command, replace `ColorFunction -> "myCF"` with `ColorFunction -> myCF`

Comment: I wasn't aware I could do that.  That simplifies things dramatically.  I appreciate it!